# Custom build step for C# project

Tags: c#

In C++ projects there is the possibility to set a custom build step for files. Is there a similar functionality in C# projects? I couldn't really find anything.

One idea would be to create a second project (makefile or c++) and move the files there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with your comment about multiple projects.  Combine this with the fact that you can include multiple projects within a single Solution and you may have your answer.  I use this functionality to build several components at a time and it works quite well.

Answer (score 2):

MsBuild should work for you although it might take some time to figure out how it works.  It appears that you can setup a step that runs prior to building each .cs file by separating each .cs file into its own build group.

In [MSBuild script for compiling each .cs file into an EXE](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/04/16/msbuild-script-for-compiling-each-cs-file-into-an-exe.aspx), Dino Chiesa comments:

> By using the %(CSFile.identity)
>   scalar, we run this task once for each
>   file.  The converse would be
>   @(CSFile.identity).  That would run
>   the compile once, for all files,
>   compiling them all together into a
>   single assembly.

Also, these links might help:

[Custom build step for C# files](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/ab3bcb1b-4ced-4e28-abd3-05c1be1156be/)

[Master Complex Builds with MSBuild](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/39347/1763)

Answer (score 1):

No custom build step for individual files with C# projects.  You could probably hack something together with MSBuild...

Answer (score 1):

Look at the BeforeBuild and AfterBuild targets in your csproj file.